# extract all values of a specific field from a struct array

Tags: octave

If i have an array like

```
 A = [
   struct( 'uid', 165215, 'type', 8, 'data', [0,3,16388,17523,12,225,225,280,242,223,256,266,261,226,225,259,210]);
   struct( 'uid', 196334, 'type', 2, 'data', [0,96,398,359,350,4,416,406,450,39]);
   % ...
   struct( 'uid', 173261, 'type', 8, 'data', [0,13,5081,5658,48]);
 ];
```

Is there a way to extract all 'type' members to a own Nx1 Matrix?
something like:

```
b = A(:).type; % this only returns "b = 8"
```

or even more complex apply logical operators on members and get a vector of answers:

```
I = A(:).type==1;
```

this throws:

```
error: binary operator '==' not implemented for 'cs-list' by 'scalar' operations
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An indexing operation like the one you used returns a cs-list (called comma separated variables in matlab). To convert it to a array or cell array, put the corresponding brackets around it:

```
 b = [A(:).type] ;
```

The line above creates an array, in case you need a cell in other cases use {} instead.  You will need it to index data.